# Firefox add-on simple-storage with time to live value?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a simple way to locally store a JSON value with a TTL in a Firefox SDK add-on?

As far as I can tell, Firefox forces you to use their `'simple-storage'` library. I can't use a third-party library such as [jStorage](http://goo.gl/yEUYg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `simple-storage` and DOM Storage are completely different things meaning that you cannot use a library like jStorage which is meant for work with DOM Storage.

Then again, storing JSON and implementing TTL is simple enough to implement yourself. For JSON you use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). For TTL you simply store the TTL values somewhere and look them up when necessary. Something like this:

```js
var AdvancedStorage = {
  _storage: require("simple-storage").storage,

  // Keep TTL data in a special storage field
  _ttlData: null,
  _readTTLData() {
    if (this._storage._ttl)
      this._ttlData = JSON.parse(this._storage._ttl);
    else
      this._ttlData = {};
  },
  _saveTTLData() {
    this._storage._ttl = JSON.stringify(this._ttlData);
  },

  // Special data manipulation functions
  set: function(key, value, options) {
    this._storage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    this.setTTL(key, options && "TTL" in options ? options.TTL : 0);
  },

  get: function(key, default) {
    if (!this._storage.hasOwnProperty(key))
      return default;

    // Check whether setting has expired
    if (!this._ttlData)
      this._readTTLData();
    if (this._ttlData.hasOwnProperty(key) && this._ttlData[key] <= Date.now())
      return default;

    return JSON.parse(this._storage[key]);
  },

  deleteKey: function(key) {
    delete this._storage[key];
  },

  // Setting the TTL value
  setTTL(key, ttl) {
    if (!this._ttlData)
      this._readTTLData();
    if (ttl > 0)
      this._ttlData[key] = Date.now() + ttl;
    else
      delete this._ttlData[key];
    this._saveTTLData();
  }
};
```

I didn't test this code but this should be pretty much all the code you need to implement this kind of feature.